# setState() doesn't setting in real time

Tags: reactjs

Hi I'm having troubles setting my component state given value through props:

```
    this.state = {
      date: '',
      dailiesInformation: [],
      isDailiesInformation: false
    };
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
    this.setState({ date: props.dateValue }, this.updateCards);
  }

  updateCards = async() => {
    const currentDate = moment(this.state.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    let dailies = await api.get(`/daily/${currentDate}`);
    this.setState({ dailiesInformation: dailies.data.allDailies });
  }
```

I want to set `dailiesInformation` property by the updateCards function, but it's setting 1 one step behind the current, I passed this function as a callback on the `componentWillReceiveProps()` function but it doesn't work.

What I'm doing wrong? thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your **SetState** needs to change

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({ date: nextProps.dateValue, dailiesInformation: this.updateCards});
}
```

but `componentWillReceiveProps` is an unsafe life-cycle hook and not a right place for an async call, please check https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops

Please don't use `componentWillReceiveProps` for this, instead consume the props directly when it comes in using your **constructor**.

```
 Constructor(props){
  super();
  this.state = {
      date: props.dateValue,
      dailiesInformation: this.updateCards,
      isDailiesInformation: false
    };
  }

  updateCards = async() => {
    const currentDate = moment(this.state.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    let dailies = await api.get(`/daily/${currentDate}`);
    return dailies.data.allDailies;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest some pattern like this (Container is ideally some global state management container). Whenever any prop of `App` (other than `dailiesInformation`) changes, the app is sending a new request via the `getDailies` and gets the result via the `dailiesInformation` prop.
Consider that `componentWillReceiveProps` is deprecated and it is recommended to use the static `getDerivedStateFromProps` instead.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state){
    const { dailiesInformation, ...otherProps } = props;

   const { dailiesInformation: prevDailyInfo, ...prevOtherProps } = state.prevProps;
    
   const isNewOtherProps = JSON.stringify(otherProps) !== JSON.stringify(prevOtherProps);
       
    if (isNewOtherProps) {
      props.getDailies();
    }
      
    return { prevProps: props }
  }
  
  
  state = {
    prevProps: { dailiesInformation: null },
  }

  render() {
    const { dailiesInformation } = this.props;
    return `dailiesInformation: ${dailiesInformation}`;
  }
}

//-------------------

class Container extends React.Component {
  handleGetDailies = () => setTimeout(() => this.setState({dailiesInformation: Math.random()}), 500);
  
  state = { dailiesInformation: 0, someProp: null }
  
  changeSomeProp = () => {
    this.setState({ someProp: Math.random() })
  }
  
  render() {
    const { dailiesInformation, someProp } = this.state;

    return (
     <div>
       <button onClick={this.changeSomeProp}>Change prop</button><br /><br />
       <App
        someProp={someProp}
        getDailies={this.handleGetDailies}
        dailiesInformation={dailiesInformation}
       />
     </div>
    )
  }
}



ReactDOM.render(<Container />, 
document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would better try the practice explained in the link below. 
It is the recommended way of receiving new props and updating states, and handling async operation at the same time:

https://gist.github.com/bvaughn/982ab689a41097237f6e9860db7ca8d6

`componentWillReceiveProps` is not the right place to call a lazy/async method.